# How to deal with CUDA version?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, environment-variables, virtualenv

How to set up different versions of CUDA in one OS?

Here is my problem: Lastest Tensorflow with GPU support requires CUDA 11.2, whereas Pytorch works with 11.3. So what is the solution to install both libraries in Windows and Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use Docker Container Environment, which would only need the Nvidia Driver to be of version `XYZ.AB`; in this way, you can use both PyTorch and TensorFlow versions.

A very good starting point for your problem would be this one(ML-WORKSPACE) : https://github.com/ml-tooling/ml-workspace

Comment: I absolutely agree and I also use Docker containers to solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am not much familiar with Docker. Are you saying that I should pull Pytorch and TF images from Docker Hub with their respective Nvidia Version?

Comment: That would be a good solution. The above link that I gave provides with with the opportunity of using both those frameworks, without the need of pulling two separate docker images. You can also start two separate docker container images from the initial image provided at the link above, if you want to use TF and PyTorch separately.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, would you be so kind as to accept it? Thank you.

Comment: Thanks Timbus that's very helpful.